# Ionic2 tab content with vertical tabs along left side

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic2(3.13) in my application, and I am able to use horizontal tabs perfectly. Is it possible to have vertical tabs, something like below, need help. Thx:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIoab.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote some scss to make it work. Hope it helps someone:

1. ionic version 3.13
2. `tabs.scss` (The tabs html file's scss file)

   ```
   page-tabs {
     .tabbar {
       top: 0;
       width: 5rem;
       flex-direction: column;
       background-color: #cfa972 !important;
     }

     ion-header {
       left: 5rem;
       right: 0;
     }

     ion-content {
       left: 5rem;
       right: 0;
     }

     .tabs-ios .tab-button {
       width: 100%;
       font-size: 10px;
       color: #cfa972;
       padding: 0;

       &[aria-selected="false"] {
         color: #cfa972 !important;
         background-color: #cfa972 !important;
       }

       &[aria-selected="true"] {
         color: #ffffff !important;
         background-color: #b28850 !important;
       }

       &[aria-selected="true"] .tab-button-icon {
         color: #ffffff;
       }

       &[aria-selected="false"] .tab-button-icon {
         color: #ffffff;
       }
     }

     .has-icon .tab-badge {
       right: calc(50% - 22px);
     }

     .tab-badge {
       top: 33%;
     }
   }
   ```
3. tab root page scss file:

   ```
   page-mine {
    .fixed-content {
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0 !important;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
    }

    .scroll-content {
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0 !important;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      display: block;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      will-change: scroll-position;
      contain: size style layout;
    }
   }
   ```